# Proof that a linear operator is continuous.

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

Could somebody please verify the following proof I have attempted? It seems too simple so I am worried I have done something wrong.. Many thanks

---

Let $T:(X,\|.\|_X)\to (Y,\|.\|_Y)$ be a linear map between Banach spaces and let $c>0$ be a constant such that for some $f:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$

$$\|Tx\|_Y\leq cf(\|x\|_X),$$
where $f$ and $c$ are independent of $x\in X$. Then $T$ is continuous.

---

*Proof*.

Observe $$\sup_{x\in X, \|x\|_X=1}\|T(x)\|_Y\leq cf(1)<+\infty$$ therefore $T$ is bounded and hence continuous.

Comment: Nothing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the argument is fine. The hypothesis is a little weird, as  the role of $f$ is, as you showed, limited to its value at $1$. And also, if $f(t)=0$ for any single $t$, that would force $T=0$.